# Poetry No file/folder found when attempting to reference another local poetry project

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have the following directory structure:

```
├── lib
│   └── stuff
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── math.py
│       ├── poetry.lock
│       └── pyproject.toml
└── services
    └── a
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── main.py
        ├── poetry.lock
        └── pyproject.toml
```

Both `services/a` and `lib/stuff` are poetry projects, they have a `pyproject.toml` file and `poetry.lock` file created by the `poetry init` process. Their contents are as follows

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "a"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Jack Evans <jack@evans.gb.net>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "stuff"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Jack Evans <jack@evans.gb.net>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
requests = "^2.31.0"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I want to be able to reference code in `lib/stuff` from within my `service/a` project.

However, when I run `poetry add ../../lib/stuff` inside `services/a` I get the following build error:

```
  • Installing stuff (0.1.0 /Users/jack/code/poetry-test/lib/stuff): Failed

  ChefBuildError

  Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/Users/jack/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/var/folders/yn/4q7r_wwd16v279lryh84bgtc0000gq/T/tmpdoxiack6/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/api.py", line 57, in build_wheel
      return WheelBuilder.make_in(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/var/folders/yn/4q7r_wwd16v279lryh84bgtc0000gq/T/tmpdoxiack6/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 80, in make_in
      wb = WheelBuilder(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/var/folders/yn/4q7r_wwd16v279lryh84bgtc0000gq/T/tmpdoxiack6/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 61, in __init__
      super().__init__(poetry, executable=executable)
    File "/var/folders/yn/4q7r_wwd16v279lryh84bgtc0000gq/T/tmpdoxiack6/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/builder.py", line 85, in __init__
      self._module = Module(
                     ^^^^^^^
    File "/var/folders/yn/4q7r_wwd16v279lryh84bgtc0000gq/T/tmpdoxiack6/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/utils/module.py", line 69, in __init__
      raise ModuleOrPackageNotFound(
  poetry.core.masonry.utils.module.ModuleOrPackageNotFound: No file/folder found for package stuff


  at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/installation/chef.py:152 in _prepare
      148│
      149│                 error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
      150│
      151│             if error is not None:
    → 152│                 raise error from None
      153│
      154│             return path
      155│
      156│     def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:

Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with stuff (0.1.0 /Users/jack/code/poetry-test/lib/stuff) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --use-pep517 "stuff @ file:///Users/jack/code/poetry-test/lib/stuff"'.
```

Is there any way to reference `lib/stuff` from within `services/a` if both poetry projects share the same common root filepath.

Comment: You're not using a standard layout, and you're also not specifying what import packages the distribution `stuff` contains in its `pyproject.toml`. You can try using one of the (two?) layouts poetry expects by default, or list the packages that `stuff` should provide in its `pyproject.toml`

Comment: Side note: it's very weird (and possible unfixably ill formed) to put a distritbution's `pyproject.toml` file inside of an import package. If you really want `a` and `stuff` to be different distributions, you should give them both their own project directories, e.g. `lib/stuff/pyproject.toml` and `lib/stuff/[src/]stuff/__init__.py`. If they don't strictly need to be different distributions, it may be simply to combine them into one distribution with several import packages.

Comment: Also, do note that it's not possible to distribute built distributions with path dependencies, since path dependencies are _required_ to be resolved to absolute paths in distribution metadata. So if you ever intend to publish this project to PyPI or build wheels from it, this structure won't work.

Comment: Follow the [documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#project-setup), your `pyproject.toml` should be in the directory _above_ your package, aka`services/pyproject.toml`. And your packages defined in the `pyproject.toml` aka: `packages = [{include = "stuff"}]`